# excel vba Insert formatted symbol in front of text keeping original formats of pre-existing text

Tags: excel, vba, character

How do I modify the code below to insert the formatted symbol at the start instead of the end?

```
Sub I___TickRedAFTERText_KeepsOtherCharFormatting()

ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count + 1, 1).Insert (" P ")

'specify location and format the new character
     With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1).Font 'second to last character in cell
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -16776961
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveCell.Characters` has two parameters: `start` and `length`

On the first line you want to insert at the beginning, with no changes to existing text/formatting. So the arguments should be `0` (i.e. the beginning) and `0` (i.e. no length, so we don't overwrite anything).

On the second line you also want to start at the beginning (so `0` again) and then format all of the characters that have been inserted (we can use the `len`gth of the text to get this).

End result:

```vb
Sub I___TickRedAFTERText_KeepsOtherCharFormatting()

    ActiveCell.Characters(0, 0).Insert(" P ")

    'specify location and format the new character
     With ActiveCell.Characters(0, Len(" P ")).Font
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -16776961
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I removed the space in front, and changed the formatting location to 'Len("P")' to exclude the following space